# SettingsActivity like Google Chrome (sub menu with radio buttons)

Tags: java, android, fragment, preferences

I am trying to recreate the settings menu from google chrome.
It should look like the image below:
[image]

What I have so far:

1. MainActivity.java
2. SettingsActivity.java
3. SettingsFragment.java
4. SettingsSearchEngineFragment.java
5. preferences.xml
6. preferences_searchengine.xml

I can't seem to find any explanations, tutorials for androidx.
I can go from the MainActivity to the SettingsActivity, but from there out I can't find a way to open my "Search Engine" Fragment(?).

How can I realize it?

Answer (score 2):

From the Android Docs:

> To manage the fragments in your activity, you need to use
> FragmentManager. To get it, call getSupportFragmentManager() from your
> activity.
>
> A great feature about using fragments in your activity is the ability
> to add, remove, replace, and perform other actions with them, in
> response to user interaction. Each set of changes that you commit to
> the activity is called a transaction and you can perform one using
> APIs in FragmentTransaction

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment searchEngineFragment = new SettingsSearchEngineFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, searchEngineFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Even though this is a viable solution, there's an approach that is much more stress-free. That is, using the Navigation Components, that work very well with Android Studio.
You'd do well to research more on it as it'd help clarify any issues you have with Navigation in Android both with Fragments, Activities and even Dialogs.

Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started